# Can you customize the User Edit page without editing the theme?

Tags: hooks, users

Is there a way to customize what appears on the user profile edit page without editing the theme? I'd much rather use blocks or hooks to accomplish this task.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels). It has a panel page for the 'user edit page' that you can edit, put blocks, views, etc.